# How to choose every next month of data in R

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a monthly dataset but not every month has proper data to work with. There is a list of the proper monthes that I want to choose. I want to select the price of the next month for each of these proper months.

For example, this is my dataset:

```
Price <- c(10,12,14,11,17,10,9,18,16,16 , 12, 13)
date <- ymd(c("1996-01-31", "1996-02-28", "1996-07-31", "1996-08-29" ,"1996-04-30" , "1996-05-28" , "1997-01-28" , "1996-09-29" , "1996-12-19", "1996-03-30" ,"1996-11-30","1996-06-30"))

Prices <- data.frame( date , Price)
```

and these are the proper months to choose:

```
proper <- ymd(c("1996-01-31", "1996-07-31" ,"1996-04-30" ,"1996-02-29" ,"1996-05-31"))
```

Now I want to have the price of very next month of `proper` in a data frame. e.g. prices of "1996-02-28" as the first element, "1996-08-29" as the second element, etc.

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired data frame? I'm unclear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert it to `yearmon` and then do the `filter`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
Prices %>% 
   filter(as.Date(as.yearmon(date)) %in% as.Date(as.yearmon(proper) + 1/12))
#        date Price
#1 1996-02-28    12
#2 1996-08-29    11
#3 1996-05-28    10
#4 1996-03-30    16
#5 1996-06-30    13
```

Comment: This was working well, thank you. In your final answer, the dates are for next month. What if I want to have the dates in the final answer to be the dates of the 'proper'? This is because I want to merge this data somewhere else and now it will not merge appropriately.

Comment: @AliEbadi  In that case, just remove the `+ 1/12`  This is to get the next month i.e. `Prices %>% 
   filter(as.Date(as.yearmon(date)) %in% as.Date(as.yearmon(proper)))`